# Jquery Date - determine a sunday?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

We have implemented a datepicker as part of a booking process using this plugin -

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

It basically populates a series of divs with month dates in columns which correspond to a day column - the issue we are having is disabling a sunday..

So - we are trying to detect the phrase sun from a date string with the following code -

```
 $('#calendar').datepick({
    pickerClass: 'noPrevNext',
    dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    altField: '[name="delivery-date"]',
    defaultDate: +7,
    minDate: +1,
    maxDate: +45,
    changeMonth: false,
    showTrigger: null,
    onSelect: function(dates)
    { 
        var jim = dates.indexOf("Sun");

        if (jim >= 0)
        {
            alert('Sundays are not selectable');
        }
    }
});
```

but we get an error stating 'indexof(sun) is not a function'

Can anyone offer any guidance please!?

Comment: What's the type of `dates` check!

Comment: It would help to have a console output on 'dates'

Comment: did you try dates.toString().indexOf("sun")?

Comment: Are you using IE8 by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see, you are using [Keith Wood Datepicker](https://github.com/kbwood/datepick) Plugin which is very similar to jquery UI plugin. In this case, your `onSelect` function receives the date Object as mentioned in:

> The function is called when each date is selected and receives the currently selected dates (Date[]) as the parameter.

So you can call the `getDay()` method straight from the `dates` array:

```
onSelect: function(dates)
{ 
    var jim = dates[0].getDay();

    if (jim == 0)
    {
        alert('Sundays are not selectable');
        $('#calendar').val("");
    }
}
```

Your problem:  `dates` variable is not a string but an array of Date objects.

Comment: Fantastic Nannodj thank you - i'll try this on Monday!